# CQWP - Raw XML Field Title

Tags: content-query-web-part

I am modifying CQWP to show items in custom way.
I found that raw output does not have column title instead has id, like following:

`_x007B_fa564e0f_x002D_0c70_x002D_4ab9_x002D_b863_x002D_0177e6ddd247_x007D_`

Please check this url for the raw output: http://pastebin.com/KM6vaR8C
Is there any way I can get internal name instead of id, like it is output in XSLT ListView WebPart.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I found "Title" field was included, so it required custom fields to be included.
I did that using [CommonViewFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.commonviewfields(v=office.14).aspx) property of CQWP.

This [blog helped](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/customitemstyle.aspx) me to put correct column type.

Here is how CommonViewFields property looks like in my case:

```
<property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">Title,Text;PlanDuration,Number;PercentComplete,Number;Project,Lookup</property>
```